# Moving connector edges in jsplumb

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I'm using the [demo of jsPlumb here:](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/statemachine/index.html)

In this demo, there's no way to move an existing connection to a different target node. Any idea how to do it?

Some of the other examples have movable connections, but they also use specific endpoints on the nodes. I like this particular example where I can drag the connection endpoint to any point of the target node.

Comment: Can you put that example on https://codepen.com or https://jsbin.com so results can be easily modified and shared by those attempting to answer your question?

Comment: It's literally just the same example that's on their website but sure why not: https://jsbin.com/qamaxaweto/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thank you, it makes life easier for people who are taking time out of their day to help you for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the connection to another target in your example,

You may just hover the mouse inside the small point, and when the cursor become à hand you can click on and move the connection to another target.

I alos do this, like in the picture, i moved some connection from their original target.

[image]